# Apache Kafka Producer Throughput and Latency

Tags: apache-kafka, performance-testing, latency, throughput

I made a Kafka Cluster on my local machine and I was testing creating producers with different Throughput to see what happens to the latency.

I used the kafka-test-perf benchmark to these tests
https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.2.10/kafka-managing/topics/kafka-manage-cli-perf-test.html

I made different tests changing the throughput for the kafka producer.

```
Test 1: 2 Throughput
Test 2: 200 Throughput
Test 3: 2,000 Throughput
Test 4: 20,000 Throughput
Test 5: 200,000 Throughput
```

[Throughput for Kafka Producer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVjd2.png)

For my perspective the throughput is the number of messages that arrive in a given amount of time.

For all tests the throughput it´s equal to the records sent by sec, except for Test 5, where the records sent by sec is 22k records/sec. Does this mean that my producer can not handle this type of throughput?

I am trying to understand the meaning of this.

I ran a lot of tests.

Comment: Throughput is defined by records or bytes per second. What makes you say it cannot handle anything?

Comment: You're testing locally which means machine type is very small I believe. It can potentially handle very large throughput. So, it can definitely handle 200k messages per second quite easily. One of the project I worked on was producing about 10 million per minute that was over 150k messages per second and it was able to handle quite easily. You just have to tune for larger volumes.

Comment: @OneCricketeer for the test I made with 200,000 throughput, the records sent by sec were roughly 22k. I say it cannot handle this type of throughput with the current configuration because of that. Am I wrong?

Comment: @PiyushPatel Yes, I understand that. What I am trying to understand is that if I defined the throughput for 200k but the records sent is only 22k/sec it means that for the current configuration it can not handle this type of throughput. Am I wrong?

Comment: From the docs - the throughput argument says `throttle maximum message throughput to *approximately* THROUGHPUT messages/sec`... Then says `Set this to -1 to disable throttling`. So, if you set `-1`, and still get 22k/sec on average, and you want more, then yeah, start/add more brokers (which you can do on a local machine), and/or more volumes in `log.dirs`. But the problem is not Kafka speeds, it's your CPU that is actually sending and counting each acked records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I don't see big difference between test 4 and test 5 which means that you reached the maximum throughput for the given hardware configuration or you need to properly tune Kafka for high loads[enter link description here](https://medium.com/@rinu.gour123/kafka-performance-tuning-ways-for-kafka-optimization-fdee5b19505b)
2. Running load generator and the application under test on the same machine is not the best idea due to [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). Also using a dedicated load testing tool like [Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/kafka-testing) can give you better control over the workload model and reporting
3. Running performance tests against scaled down environment won't tell you the full story and you won't be able to extrapolate the results especially for complex applications like Kafka, you need to run your tests against production or production-like environment, this way you will be able to get accurate metrics
4. I would recommend increasing the load gradually, this way you will be able to correlate the increasing load with increasing throughput, will be able to determine the [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) and the [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing) more precisely.